# Can't seem to print characters properly in array

Tags: java, arrays

I am trying to print a pyramid made of '*' using array methods 5x5 or 7x7 or 9x9 or 11x11 according to the user input.

My code right now prints half pyramid, can't seem to get the other half. Help would be very appreciated.

```
public static char[][] pointUp (char asterik, int length){
        char [] [] pointUp = new char [length] [length];
        for (int i = 0; i < length; i++){
            for (int j = 0; j < length; j++) {
                pointUp[i][j] = ' ';
            }
        }

        int end = length; 
        int j = 0;
        for (int column = 0; column < end; column++) {
            for (int row = j; row <= length/2; row++) {
                pointUp[row][column] = asterik;
            }
            j++;
            end++;

        }
        return pointUp;
    }
```

expected for 5x5 code:

```
    *   
  * * *
* * * * *

(space intended for remaining 2 columns)
```

expected for 7x7 code and so on:

```
      *
    * * * 
  * * * * * 
* * * * * * *

(space intended for remaining 3 columns)
```

what i get for 7x7 code and so on(other half missing):

```
 *            
 * *          
 * * *        
 * * * *   

(space intended for remaining 3 columns)
```

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you want?

```
class test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        testPointUp(21);
    }

    public static char[][] pointUp(char asterisk, int length) {
        // make sure length is odd, other wise you can't do this
        // I encourage to make your own Exception class for clarity (e.g. NotOddException)
        if (length % 2 == 0) 
            throw new RuntimeException("Can't make a pyramide with an even lower row");

        // make the desired return value
        char[][] ret = new char[length][length];

        // if you devide the length parameter by two and avoid the .5, you
        // get the amount of empty columns in the first row, decrement this every
        // for every row, do this while emptyCols >= 0
        int emptyCols = (int) length/2;
        int row = 0;
        int desiredAsterisks = 1;
        while (emptyCols >= 0) {
            // first, add all empty cols
            for (int i = 0; i < emptyCols; i++) {
                ret[row][i] = ' ';
            }
            // then, add the desired amount of asterisks
            for (int i = 0; i < desiredAsterisks; i++) {
                ret[row][i + emptyCols] = asterisk;
            }
            // and of course, add the remaining empty cols
            for (int i = emptyCols + desiredAsterisks; i < length; i++) {
                ret[row][i] = ' ';
            }
            // change all necessary variables
            emptyCols--;
            desiredAsterisks += 2;
            row++;
        }
        return ret;
    }

    public static void testPointUp(int length) {
        char[][] test = pointUp('*', length);
        // I use a StringBuilder rather then a String because I want to
        // append a lot of characters to the variable I want to print out
        // in the end. Strings are immutable so every time you concatenate a String
        // a new variable is being made and given to the String variable, using a 
        // StringBuilder is much more efficient in concatenating (appending).
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder("");
        for (int i = 0; i < length; i ++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < length; j++) {
                sb.append(test[i][j]);
            }
            sb.append("\n");
        }
        System.out.println(sb);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Well there you go!

```
public static char[][] pointUp(char asterik, int length) {
    char[][] pointUp = new char[length][length];
    int halfLength = length / 2;
    for (int i = 0; i < halfLength + 1; i++) {
        int end = halfLength - i;
        for (int j = 0; j < end; j++) {
            pointUp[i][j] = ' ';
        }
        for (int k = 0; k < 2 * i + 1; k++)
            pointUp[i][k + end] = asterik;
    }

    return pointUp;
}
```

Break down the pattern into series, then try to solve the smaller series and build up your solution.